# Eagle model for TO-220F-4L

Tags: eaglecad, cad, to220

Where can I find an Eagle model for the TO-220F-4L package? Or something similar?

I'm trying to add a [KA78RXXC-Series Voltage Regulator](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1639827.pdf) and I can't even find another component with the same pins.

[image: TO-220F-4L package]

Comment: The time you spend searching for one is probably better spent building your own.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I thought that until I found SnapEDA (see my answer).  Now if I don't find it there, I don't bother searching elsewhere and make my own.

Answer (score 2):

SnapEDA to the rescue!  Go to [their website](http://www.snapeda.com/parts/) and type in KA78RXXC into the search box and click on Search.

Comes up with six parts, several in the TO-220F-4L package.  Click on the part #, and then the orange Download button to select an Eagle footprint.

If a dialog box comes up saying "Converting file...", that will be followed by a Save File As dialog and you can save off the .lbr file.  If when pressing the Download button and selecting an Eagle footprint and nothing happens, there is no footprint available for Eagle.

What amazes me is you can enter a generic name from the top of a datasheet (like KA78RXXC) and it will come back with a list of specific parts (e.g. KA78R15CTU).  Pretty good search engine!

Usually a great free source of footprints -- however based on a comment below, it turns out the footprint they have for this particular part is wrong -- should be a TO220 with 4 leads, but they show only three.

Comment: Do those work in Eagle?  (I always end up making my own parts.. bigger pads/ holes  or some other change.)

Comment: @GeorgeHerold I think I said that in my answer: "select an Eagle footprint."  Their dropdown list for the Download button lists Eagle, Altium, KiCad, and OrCAD.  I used to have to make a  lot of my own parts.  Hardly any since I discovered this site.

Comment: The ones on SnapEDA say they're 4 pin, but they are actually 3. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Nicolas Sorry about that!  I didn't pay attention  to the picture of the footprint on their website.  Odd they had the correct part number, even had a picture with 4 pins, but only had 3-pin footprints.  Shame on them (and me).  I'll leave my answer up though as it is still a good resource most of the time.  Meanwhile I'll leave feedback on their site that the footprints are wrong.